# "To ..., to ..., and to ..." multiple to-infinitives

Tags: grammar, infinitives

Usually, I just use one "to", in sentences like "**To** address this problem and share our ideas with others, we would like to ...".

But I also see people use multiple "to"s, like "**To** address this problem and **to** share our ideas with others, we would like to ..."

Are they both correct?

Comment: Infinitive _to_ complementizers, like prepositions, articles, subject pronouns, and auxiliary verbs, are often deleted when repeated. The process is called [_Conjunction Reduction_](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A15299%20conjunction%20reduction) because it reduces the size of conjoined phrases and clauses. Conjunction reduction is optional, as you note, so whether you delete them (for convenience and speed) or repeat them  (for emphasis) is up to you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, that answers my question exactly. Especially, this link: https://300daysofbetterwriting.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/repeat-to-when-using-infinitives-in-a-complex-series/

Comment: *The rare African moth is known to drink blood from recently dead animals, to follow herds of elephants for miles, often for months at a time, in both rainy and dry seasons, and to make noises with its wings, which resemble the rattle of a snake, to frighten away potential competitors.* I'm not sure it's all that helpful to say that sentence becomes "much clearer" once you understand that the "infinitive marker" ***to*** may be "deleted" where it occurs on multiple consecutive occasions within a list. That sentence is stylistically appalling anyway, so maybe it shouldn't be used as an example.